# Flutter ui.Image Memory Leak Issue When Overwriting and Disposing

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter application, users can draw on top of an image. After each drawing action, I convert these paths into a ui.Image object. I then overwrite the previous ui.Image with the new one and attempt to dispose of the old one. However, I've noticed that the memory consumption of the application keeps increasing with each drawing action. This behavior suggests that the old ui.Image objects are not being disposed of correctly.

I tried overwriting the ui.Image object and then disposing of the old one to free up memory. I was expecting the memory used by the old ui.Image objects to be released, but this does not seem to be happening. Even though I'm calling the dispose method, the memory is not being freed up as expected. This issue is leading to increased memory consumption over time, especially as users continue to draw on the image.

I've observed this behavior in Flutter version 3.13.5.

Here's the complete code for my implementation:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PaintApp(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PaintApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaintAppState createState() => _PaintAppState();
}

class _PaintAppState extends State<PaintApp> {
  List<Path> paths = [];
  List<Path> cachedPaths = [];
  ui.Image? _uiImage;
  double _imageScale = 1.0;

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      final data = await image.readAsBytes();
      await loadImage(data);
      final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      _imageScale = screenSize.width / _uiImage!.width;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadImage(Uint8List img) async {
    final completer = Completer<ui.Image>();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    _uiImage = await completer.future;
  }

  void cacheStroke() {
    final oldImage = _uiImage;
    final newImage = toUiImage();
    setState(() {
      _uiImage = newImage;
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      oldImage?.dispose();
    });
  }


  ui.Image toUiImage() {
    final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final cacheCanvas = Canvas(recorder);

    cacheCanvas.drawImage(
      _uiImage!,
      Offset.zero,
      Paint(),
    );


    for (var path in paths) {
      if (paths.contains(path)) continue;
      cacheCanvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..strokeWidth = 30
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      );
      cachedPaths.add(path);
    }
    final newPicture = recorder.endRecording();
    final newImage = newPicture.toImageSync(_uiImage!.width, _uiImage!.height);

    newPicture.dispose();
    return newImage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Paint App'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
              onPressed: getImage,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onPanStart: (details) {
            final newPath = Path()..moveTo(details.localPosition.dx / _imageScale, details.localPosition.dy / _imageScale);
            setState(() {
              paths.add(newPath);
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            setState(() {
              paths.last.lineTo(details.localPosition.dx / _imageScale, details.localPosition.dy / _imageScale);
            });
            print(details.localPosition);
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            cacheStroke();
          },
          child: (_uiImage != null) ? CustomPaint(
            size: Size(_uiImage!.width.toDouble() * _imageScale, _uiImage!.height.toDouble() * _imageScale),
            painter: MyPainter(_uiImage, paths, _imageScale),
          ) : Container(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image? image;
  final List<Path> paths;
  final List<Path> cachedPaths = [];
  final double imageScale;

  MyPainter(this.image, this.paths, this.imageScale);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.scale(imageScale, imageScale);
    if (image != null) {
      canvas.drawImage(image!, Offset(0, 0), Paint());
    }

    for (final path in paths) {
      if (cachedPaths.contains(path)) continue;
      canvas.drawPath(
        path,
        Paint()
          ..strokeWidth = 30
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
          ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round
      );
    }

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```